# first date field should not be greater than second date field value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Currently working on jQuery date with my current code where i can able to select the date in both the fields I want to check if user select the passport date should not be greater than expiry date.

This is my current jquery code

```
    function testDates() {
    var from = new Date(Date.parse($("#txt_Idt").attr("value")));
    var to = new Date(Date.parse($("#txt_Epdt").attr("value")));
    if (from > to) {
        alert("From is greater than to!");
        return;
    }
    // alert("do submit");
}
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/p5y1dubq/1/)

Comment: how do you want to validate? onkeyup from the the inputs or on button press?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply by using onkeyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onSelect` event of datepicker

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".txt_Idt").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
     yearRange: '-115:+1M',
     maxDate: new Date(),
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var expDate = new Date($("#txt_Epdt").val());
       var ppt = new Date(dateText);
       if (ppt > expDate) {
         alert(" Passport date is greater than Expiry Date!");
         return;
       } else
         alert(dateText);
     }
   });
   $(".txt_Epdt").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
     yearRange: '-115:+95M',
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var from = new Date($("#txt_Idt").val());
       var to = new Date(dateText);
       if (from > to) {
         alert("From is greater than to!");
         return;
       } else
         alert(dateText);
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Passport Date" class="ipt_Field txt_Idt ipt_required" id="txt_Idt" name="txt_Idt" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Expiry Date" class="ipt_Field txt_Epdt ipt_required" id="txt_Epdt" name="txt_Epdt" />
```

Comment: I am not getting alert if user select first expiry date (10/01/2015) issue date as (10/08/2015)

Comment: Use select event for `passport` datepicker also.

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p5y1dubq/3/)**

Use `onSelect` option of `datePicker` [assuming `jquery-ui datepicker` from the fiddle] and change `minDate` and `maxDate` of `toDate` and `fromDate` respectively as below and make your input `readonly` so that user `input` is prevented.

```
$(".txt_Idt").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    yearRange: '-115:+1M',
    maxDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $(".txt_Epdt").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
    }
});
$(".txt_Epdt").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    yearRange: '-115:+95M',
    onSelect:function(dateText) {
        $(".txt_Idt").datepicker('option','maxDate',dateText);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Passport Date" class="ipt_Field txt_Idt ipt_required" 
   id="txt_Idt" name="txt_Idt" readonly /> <!--Add readonly here-->
<input type="text" placeholder="Expiry Date" class="ipt_Field txt_Epdt ipt_required" 
   id="txt_Epdt" name="txt_Epdt" readonly /><!--Add readonly here-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple date comparision example using jQuery. Basically just use the `Date` object and then compare them:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#date1').datepicker();
    $('#date2').datepicker();

    $('#date2').on('change', function () {
        var date1 = new Date($('#date1').val());
        var date2 = new Date($('#date2').val());
        console.log(date1);
        console.log(date2);

        if (date1 > date2) {
            alert("date1 is greater than date2");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi is that possible to do on keypress instead of btnGo

Comment: Certainly. However, which field would you want the key press on? If they haven't filled in both dates, then errors will be thrown (unless you do proper error handling, of course). In any case, I updated the code so that it triggers once the user enters a value for date2